# Update Fragment when new element is added to database

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I'm writing an android app. The app is able to get Push notifications from Parse, and I have been able to take the notification from Parse and put it into an SQLiteDatabase. I have a fragment which, when selected from Navigation Drawer, reads the values from the database and displays them with a Custom Adapter. This is where I need help.

If the user has the Notifications tab currently selected and a new Push notification is received, the notification is put in the database but not displayed until the user navigates away from the Notifications tab and back into the Notifications tab. I'm ok with this, but I'd like the Notifications fragment to update immediately upon Push reception. Is there any way to set a listener on the database to implement this behavior?

Thanks for any replies - I'm able to paste code if it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) may be what you're looking for. [This](https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps--ud853) Udacity course helped me understand how to use Loaders.

Through a Loader/LoaderManager, the `onLoadFinished` method is called in your fragment/activity when the database is updated. Seeing you are using a SQLite DB, you could use a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html), which would pass a Cursor in to `onLoadFinished` and then you can do whatever you want with it, such as send it to an Adapter to display the new data.

Comment: This sounds like a great concept! I'm going to try and implement it, then post back here with my solution.

Comment: Did using a Loader help out? If not, what did you end up using to solve this?

Comment: I'm in the process of implementing the loader... using this tutorial:
http://www.phloxblog.in/android-custom-loader-load-data-sqlite-database-android-version-1-6/#.VkpFeiCrTVM

I'm having trouble with the onCreateLoader method, though. Android Studio isn't recognizing my SQLiteTestDataLoader as a legitimate Loader. Any help here?

Comment: Just finished implementing. It doesn't update the fragment automatically, but I think that I may have to tweak my code to get that behavior. Things are working fine, just be sure in your import statements you're consistently using android.content.AsyncTaskLoader or android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.